# Null Pointer in BinarySearchTreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary, insert, nullpointerexception, binary-search-tree

I'm completing a `BinarySearchTreeMap` class that is exactly how it sounds like it is: its a Map implemented with a Binary Search Tree.

I seem to be getting a Null pointer exception that I just can't get a grip on. I figure this has happened to others in similar situations. I was given the method in question and my logic seems correct, so if anyone has any hints or tips on why there is a null pointer and how I can prevent these in the future please let me know!

Below is the method that I am creating - inserts an entry at an external node:

```
    /** Auxiliary method for inserting an entry at an external node.  Inserts e 
    *  at v, expanding v to be internal with empty external children, and then 
    *  returns e. */
    protected Entry<K,V> insertAtExternal(Position<Entry<K,V>> v, Entry<K,V> e) throws InvalidEntryException{
        if(isInternal(v)) throw new InvalidEntryException("You tried to insert an external at an  internal node!");
        replaceEntry(v,e); //replace the node at the given position
        insertLeft(v,null); //insert a dummy external node to the left of it
        insertRight(v,null); //insert a dummy external node to the right of it

        numEntries++; //since v is now internal, include it in the numEntries
        return e;

    }


    protected V replaceEntry(Position <Entry<K,V>> pos, Entry<K,V> ent) {
        ((BSTEntry<K,V>) ent).pos = pos;
        return replace(pos, ent).getValue();
    }
```

The return statement is line thats causing me trouble.
Any help would be appreciate.
Claudia

EDIT:
This is how the replace method is implemented:

```
replace(Position<E> v, E o) 
throws InvalidPositionException {
BTPosition<E> vv = checkPosition(v);
E temp = v.element();
vv.setElement(o);
return temp;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: What does the replace method look like?